# Internet not connected after sleep wake even though wifi is connected after awake

Tags: mac, network, wifi, sleep-wake, mac-pro

OS X EI Captain (version 10.11.5).
This issues is consistent, whenever Mac awakes from sleep, My internet is disconnected. I tried the following options,

1. Turn off wifi and turn back on.
2. Restart network service by `sudo ifconfig em0 down` and up.Basically restarting network services.
3. Network settings to renew DHCP address, Prioritizing the wifi in service order.

Comment: Have you tried these steps Dinesh? They may help: http://osxdaily.com/2014/04/24/fix-mac-disconnect-wifi-sleep/

Comment: @Ian yes, I have tried it. It doesn't seems to work.

Comment: Have you investigated what the command line tool `airport` can do for you? It has a few more options than those that are available in the GUI: https://www.itdojo.com/osx-airport-cli-tool-not-just-for-airport-aps/ I've had good results occasionally with the tool.

Comment: I've been having the same problem since a few years with my mid 2014 macbook, now running Sierra. I tried every solution I could find, and although it seems fixed sometimes, the problem always comes back. I recently did a clean (not TM restore) install of my macbook as a last resort, and it didn't help -_-

Comment: I still have this annoying issue with "MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2014" that runs  "maxOS high sierra 10.13.4". any solutions ?

Comment: Still having the issue on macOS Monterey 12.6.6, Macbook Air M2. FWIW, during this issue, if I connect a network cable, I can access internet. So the problem is most certainly pertaining to some issue with WiFi.

Comment: @Jonny when did your problem appear? I've had the same issue appear out of nowhere on M1 Pro with macOS 13.4, not obviously correlated with any update/installation. It's interesting you seem to be having the getting the same problem around the same time as me, 5 years after the last comment.

Comment: I've been having this problem now and then for at least a couple of years over a couple of Macs, like Macbook Pros and Macbook Airs. It's not an every day thing, but happens like maybe a few times a month. And each time I'm like "oh no, not again" and it basically means I have to restart the computer every time.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue on one of my machines running both macOS Catalina and Big Sur. Tried forgetting the network and joining again, doing an SMC reset, and a few other solutions with no luck.

I was finally able to find a fix for it today (also posted it here https://alihaghani.me/blog/fix-mac-not-having-internet-access-on-wake):

1. Go to System Preference → Network
2. Select 'Advanced...' in the bottom right corner
3. Go to the TCP/IP tab
4. Enter 'ConnecMac' in the DHCP Client ID field
5. Select 'Renew DHCP Lease' above the field
6. Press OK
7. In the System Preferences → Network, select the Location dropdown
8. Select 'Edit Locations...'
9. Select the plus sign to add a new location
10. Enter 'Home' as its name

Answer (score 1):

You may try this , i had same issue. 
Your computer may be set to disconnect automatically
If you have to redial your dial-up modem Internet connection after not using your Mac for a few moments, or reconnect your PPPoE connection, your Mac may be set to disconnect automatically when the connection is idle.

1.Choose Apple menu > System Preferences, then click Network.

2.Select your modem port (internal or external) or your PPPoE configuration      in the list at the left, then click Advanced.

3.Click PPP, then make sure “Prompt every __ minutes to maintain  connection” is not selected, or if it is selected, increase the number of minutes that the computer can remain idle before disconnecting.

Comment: I could see such a configuration in Network.

Comment: Surely that's only if the mac is connected directly to the ISP equipment and bypassing the router entirely? As I understand it, Dinesh is having trouble with his wifi not reconnecting after his mac wakes...?

Comment: It didn't work.