# Macbook Internet Issue After Wake-up (Connected but no Internet)

Tags: network, wifi, sleep-wake, internet

This problem is consistent and many people [reported the same issue](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/249520/internet-not-connected-after-sleep-wake-even-though-wifi-is-connected-after-awak) with no apparent solution. Often (not always) whenever my 2019 MacBook and 2017 iMac wakes from sleep, the WiFi gets connected but I get no Internet. I’m Running macOS Monterey on both, but this problem has been reported since Catalina!

---

The solutions that **do not** work include:

1. Turning on/off WiFi
2. Connecting to other WiFi access points
3. Using Apple’s WiFi diagnostics by pressing <kbd>Option</kbd> key and clicking on the WiFi button
4. The solution with 'Renew DHCP Lease' provided [here](https://alihaghani.me/blog/fix-mac-not-having-internet-access-on-wake/)

---

The only thing that **works** is to restart the Mac!!

Comment: Please [Edit] your question with a summary of the solution found in #4. It’s better if you don't send folks off site to figure out what you did.  Keep the link, but give at least one sentence describing it.

Comment: @Allan done. thanks

Comment: Facing same issue on an M1 Pro on macOS 13.4. The problem suddenly started, not clearly related to any update or software installation. Any tips for debugging would be great.

Comment: More nuggets: The Mac assigns itself a 169.254.*.* IP address. Assigning a static IP in the router does not help the Mac use a good IP. Assigning the same static IP in the Mac appears to make it use the IP but does not fix the problem.